# Error: (vsim-3544) TEXTIO procedure READ(BIT_VECTOR) : Cannot get value from "9"

Tags: vhdl

The code is from [How to Read Image in VHDL](https://www.fpga4student.com/2018/08/how-to-read-image-in-vhdl.html)

The author said it's synthesizable, but it's not like what he or she said.
When I am simulating the code, ModelSim gives me the following message:

**"Error: (vsim-3544) TEXTIO procedure READ(BIT_VECTOR) : Cannot get value from "9". "**

I believe the function is problematic.

```
TYPE mem_type IS ARRAY(0 TO IMAGE_SIZE) OF std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) DOWNTO 0);

impure function init_mem(mif_file_name : in string) return mem_type is
    file mif_file : text open read_mode is mif_file_name;
    variable mif_line : line;
    variable temp_bv : bit_vector(DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    variable temp_mem : mem_type;
begin
    for i in mem_type'range loop
        readline(mif_file, mif_line);
        read(mif_line, temp_bv);
        temp_mem(i) := to_stdlogicvector(temp_bv);
    end loop;
    return temp_mem;
end function;
```

What's wrong here? I couldn't find the error.

A snippet of my mif file.

```
WIDTH=16;
DEPTH=96000;
ADDRESS_RADIX=UNS;
DATA_RADIX=BIN;

CONTENT BEGIN
0      :   1110111100111000;
1      :   1110011011111000;
2      :   1110111101111011;
3      :   1111011110111100;
4      :   1100111000110111;
5      :   1100011000010111;
6      :   1111011111011100;
7      :   1111111111111101;
8      :   1100011000111000;
9      :   1011110111110111;
10      :   1111111111111111;
11      :   1100011000010111;
12      :   1100011000010111;
13      :   1111111111111101;
14      :   1101111011111010;
15      :   1100011000110111;
16      :   1100011000010111;
17      :   1111011110111100;
18      :   1111111110111101;
19      :   1100011000111000;
20      :   1110111101111100;
21      :   1110111101011011;
22      :   1100010111110111;
23      :   1110011011111011;
24      :   1111111111011101;
```

Comment: are there '0' and '1' characters in your file?

Comment: @TEMLIB yes. Please have a look at update

Comment: The VHDL readline and read procedures don't traverse memory initialization format (.mif) files without a [lot more parsing](https://github.com/awersatos/AD/tree/master/Library/HDL%20Simulation/Altera%20QuartusII%209.1%20VHDL%20Libraries/lpm/src) (See LPM_ROM in 220model.vhd). Note the displayed image file contents in your [link](https://www.fpga4student.com/2018/08/how-to-read-image-in-vhdl.html) contain a number of sequential binary values only, the number of lines equal to the mem_type array size.

Comment: What makes the TEXTIO reading memory contents synthesis eligible is it's executed during elaboration to provide an (initial) value expression for an object declaration (not shown here).

Comment: Without changing the init_mem function you can [demonstrate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCYro.jpg) simplifying the file being read will work.

Comment: @user16145658 simplifying the file being read is the probably the only way out.

I am wondering how I can store this info for my DE10-Lite board.

"Error (170040): Can't place all RAM cells in design
 Info (170034): Selected device has 182 memory locations of type M9K. The current design requires 192 memory locations of type M9K to successfully fit."